# React JS: Material UI, Textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I am writting a textfield in ReactJS (using Material UI) to store numbers. I want the default value to be one of my state variables, but I want to allow the user to be able to change the value by clicking one on the up/down arrow, and then have the state changed to that new value when the user clicks a button.

This is the textfield code I have right now:

```
<TextField className={classes.numberClicker}
      id="bedTemperature"
      type="number"
      value = {this.state.bedTemp}
      inputProps={{
          step: "0.1"
      }}
/>
```

My problem is, when I have the value set to {this.state.bedTemp}, I am unable to change the value using the up/down arrow. I understand that I need sometype of onChange handler, but I am not sure how write that function to differentiate between the up/down arrows.

Any ideas? For reference, this is how the textfield looks like:

[image: Picture of textfield]

Comment: You are looking for a controlled component.  It's in the React docs under "Forms" but this is probably a better read, imho: https://dmitripavlutin.com/controlled-inputs-using-react-hooks/

Answer (score 0):

set your state in a handlechange like so:

```
<TextField className={classes.numberClicker}
      id="bedTemperature"
      type="number"
      value = {this.state.bedTemp}
      onChange={(e)=> this.setState({...state, bedTemp: e.target.value})}
      inputProps={{
          step: "0.1"
      }}
/>
```

is the button an absolute must? under this current model it would remove the need for a button and they could just type the number or use the arrows and the input value would update along with the state